# SQL cloud import is taking too long

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to import several sql files to sql cloud database. The import action using gsutil is met with this exception

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud sql instances import
>   prova0 gs:// bucket_tmp/00005tickerwoeu.sql --database=prova0
>   Importing Cloud SQL instance...done. ERROR:
>   (gcloud.sql.instances.import) Operation
>   https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1
>   beta3/projects/ivory-folder-123456/instances/prova0/operations
>
> /89d123456-5b06-aec2-fb0ee65 is taking too long

While if I use the console.developers interface for import it does not work as it should. It claims to be running (and probably does as I see an increase of 30 mb in db size in one hour) or simply raises a

> "An unknown error occurred" error.

Background: I have a D1 database with 5 gb in it (the inserts in the mysqldump extend the bigger tables). The database was originally in MyISAM format, but I changed the two main tables to InnoDB (in sql-cloud db) after importing a dump raised a "mysql_query Incorrect key file for table './prova0/tickers.MYI'; try to repair it" error.

All the inserts are on the tables for which I changed the engine, and the problems importing start to happen after the change.

When I query the tables I seem to get the right output. But why are inserts no longer working/working at 500kb/min (they comprise varchar, integers and dates)?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL provides suggestion if import takes too long:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export#longproc

Comment: I tried all suggestions, to no avail. I have a pretty large table, 30% of which is index, which I am dumping and uploading with this result: The sqlcloud import tool works fine until I have uploaded 2.5 GB, and then for some reason it hits a wall and it stops working. Also the web facility produces an error. I could be waiting all day and the first insert wouldnt be executed.
2015/10/30 19:36:31 0.00    1427ms      27 "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"\n
2015/10/30 19:36:31 0.00     178ms      22 "SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;"\n
2015/10/30 19:36:31 0.00     177ms      19 "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;"\n

Comment: Update. I changed the tier of the cloudsql instance and now I can insert more data. But what ceiling did I hit? Supposedly instances have a 250gb storage limit, but I am not sure. Then it could be the memory, does it sound correct?